# Arduino Pro Mini Splash Screen

Tags: c, arduino, splash-screen

I want to build this Altimeter: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=mMiMNTv25Bw. While I was waiting for the parts to arrive, I started looking over the code. I have a Splash.c file. 
This is the code in the file:

*

```
// Splash.c
// Font type    : Splash Screen
// Font size    : 128x64 pixels
// Memory usage : 1024 bytes
#include <avr/pgmspace.h>
uint8_t Splash[] PROGMEM={
  0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 
  0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 
  0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 
  0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 
  0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 
  0x0f, 0xff, 0xbf, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 
  0x0f, 0xff, 0xbf, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x30, 0x00, 0x00, 
  0x0f, 0xff, 0xbf, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x78, 0x01, 0xc0, 
  0x0f, 0xff, 0xbf, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x78, 0x01, 0xc0, 
  0x0f, 0xff, 0xbf, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x04, 0x78, 0x01, 0xc0, 
  0x01, 0xf8, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x0e, 0x20, 0x01, 0xc0, 
  0x01, 0xf8, 0x3f, 0x3f, 0xfc, 0x7e, 0x7e, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x0c, 0xe0, 0x01, 0xc0, 
  0x01, 0xf8, 0x3f, 0x3f, 0xfe, 0x7e, 0x7e, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x1d, 0xf0, 0x03, 0xc0, 
  0x01, 0xf8, 0x3f, 0x3f, 0xff, 0x7e, 0x7e, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x1b, 0xf8, 0x0f, 0xc0, 
  0x01, 0xf8, 0x3f, 0x3f, 0xff, 0x7e, 0x7e, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x3b, 0xfc, 0x0f, 0xc0, 
  0x01, 0xf8, 0x3f, 0x3f, 0x3f, 0x7e, 0x7e, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x37, 0xef, 0x9f, 0xc0, 
  0x01, 0xf8, 0x3f, 0x3f, 0x3f, 0x7e, 0x7e, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x07, 0xc7, 0xdf, 0xc0, 
  0x01, 0xf8, 0x3f, 0x3f, 0x3f, 0x7e, 0x7e, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x0f, 0xc0, 0x9f, 0xc0, 
  0x01, 0xf8, 0x3f, 0x3f, 0x3f, 0x7e, 0x7e, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x0f, 0xc0, 0x3f, 0xc0, 
  0x01, 0xf8, 0x3f, 0x3f, 0x3f, 0x7e, 0x7e, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x0f, 0xf0, 0x1f, 0xc0, 
  0x01, 0xf8, 0x3f, 0x3f, 0x3f, 0x7e, 0x7e, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x0f, 0xf8, 0x1f, 0xc0, 
  0x01, 0xf8, 0x3f, 0x3f, 0x3f, 0x7e, 0x7e, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x0e, 0x78, 0x0f, 0xc0, 
  0x01, 0xf8, 0x3f, 0x3f, 0x3f, 0x7e, 0x7e, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x0e, 0x18, 0x0f, 0xc0, 
  0x01, 0xf8, 0x3f, 0x3f, 0x3f, 0x7f, 0xfe, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x0e, 0x1c, 0x0f, 0xc0, 
  0x01, 0xf8, 0x3f, 0x3f, 0x3f, 0x7f, 0xfe, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x0e, 0x1c, 0x1f, 0xc0, 
  0x01, 0xf8, 0x3f, 0x3f, 0x3f, 0x3f, 0xfe, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x0e, 0x1c, 0xff, 0xc0, 
  0x01, 0xf8, 0x3f, 0x3f, 0x3f, 0x00, 0x7e, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x1c, 0x09, 0xff, 0xc0, 
  0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x7e, 0x7e, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x1c, 0x01, 0xff, 0xc0, 
  0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x7f, 0xfe, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x38, 0x3f, 0xff, 0xc0, 
  0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x7f, 0xfe, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x38, 0x7f, 0xff, 0xc0, 
  0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x3f, 0xfc, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x10, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 
  0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x1f, 0xf8, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 
  0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 
  0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 
  0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 
  0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 
  0xff, 0xff, 0xff, 0xff, 0xff, 0xff, 0xff, 0xff, 0xff, 0xff, 0xff, 0xff, 0xff, 0xff, 0xff, 0xff, 
  0xff, 0xff, 0xff, 0xff, 0xff, 0xff, 0xff, 0xff, 0xff, 0xff, 0xff, 0xff, 0xff, 0xff, 0xff, 0xff, 
  0xff, 0x00, 0x7c, 0x0f, 0xff, 0x03, 0xff, 0xff, 0xff, 0xff, 0xff, 0xff, 0xff, 0xff, 0xff, 0xff, 
  0xff, 0x00, 0x7c, 0x0f, 0xff, 0x03, 0xff, 0xff, 0xff, 0xff, 0xff, 0xff, 0xff, 0xff, 0xff, 0xff, 
  0xff, 0x00, 0x7c, 0x0e, 0x0f, 0x03, 0xff, 0xff, 0xff, 0xff, 0xff, 0xc1, 0xff, 0xff, 0xff, 0xff, 
  0xfe, 0x00, 0x7c, 0x0e, 0x0f, 0x03, 0xff, 0xff, 0xff, 0xff, 0xff, 0xc1, 0xff, 0xff, 0xff, 0xff, 
  0xfe, 0x00, 0x3c, 0x0e, 0x0f, 0x03, 0xff, 0xff, 0xff, 0xff, 0xff, 0xc1, 0xff, 0xff, 0xff, 0xff, 
  0xfe, 0x00, 0x3c, 0x0e, 0x0f, 0xff, 0xff, 0xff, 0xff, 0xff, 0xff, 0xc1, 0xff, 0xff, 0xff, 0xff, 
  0xfe, 0x08, 0x3c, 0x0c, 0x01, 0x03, 0x02, 0x06, 0x07, 0xe0, 0x07, 0x80, 0x3c, 0x00, 0xf0, 0x23, 
  0xfe, 0x08, 0x3c, 0x0c, 0x01, 0x03, 0x00, 0x00, 0x03, 0xc0, 0x01, 0x80, 0x38, 0x00, 0x30, 0x03, 
  0xfc, 0x08, 0x3c, 0x0c, 0x01, 0x03, 0x00, 0x00, 0x03, 0x80, 0x01, 0x80, 0x30, 0x00, 0x30, 0x03, 
  0xfc, 0x08, 0x1c, 0x0c, 0x01, 0x03, 0x00, 0x00, 0x03, 0x80, 0x01, 0x80, 0x30, 0x00, 0x30, 0x03, 
  0xfc, 0x18, 0x1c, 0x0c, 0x01, 0x03, 0x03, 0x03, 0x83, 0x80, 0x01, 0x80, 0x30, 0x00, 0x30, 0x3f, 
  0xfc, 0x1c, 0x1c, 0x0e, 0x0f, 0x03, 0x03, 0x03, 0x83, 0x81, 0xc1, 0xc1, 0xf0, 0x38, 0x30, 0x3f, 
  0xfc, 0x1c, 0x1c, 0x0e, 0x0f, 0x03, 0x03, 0x03, 0x83, 0x81, 0xc1, 0xc1, 0xf0, 0x38, 0x30, 0x3f, 
  0xfc, 0x1c, 0x1c, 0x0e, 0x0f, 0x03, 0x03, 0x03, 0x83, 0x81, 0x81, 0xc1, 0xf0, 0x30, 0x30, 0x3f, 
  0xf8, 0x00, 0x1c, 0x0e, 0x0f, 0x03, 0x03, 0x03, 0x83, 0x80, 0x01, 0xc1, 0xf0, 0x00, 0x30, 0x3f, 
  0xf8, 0x00, 0x0c, 0x0e, 0x0f, 0x03, 0x03, 0x03, 0x83, 0x80, 0xff, 0xc1, 0xf0, 0x1f, 0xf0, 0x3f, 
  0xf8, 0x00, 0x0c, 0x0e, 0x0f, 0x03, 0x03, 0x03, 0x83, 0x81, 0xff, 0xc1, 0xf0, 0x3f, 0xf0, 0x3f, 
  0xf8, 0x00, 0x0c, 0x0e, 0x0f, 0x03, 0x03, 0x03, 0x83, 0x81, 0xff, 0xc1, 0xf0, 0x3f, 0xf0, 0x3f, 
  0xf8, 0x00, 0x0c, 0x0e, 0x01, 0x03, 0x03, 0x03, 0x83, 0x80, 0x01, 0xc0, 0x30, 0x00, 0x30, 0x3f, 
  0xf8, 0x1c, 0x0c, 0x0e, 0x01, 0x03, 0x03, 0x03, 0x83, 0x80, 0x01, 0xc0, 0x30, 0x00, 0x30, 0x3f, 
  0xf0, 0x3c, 0x0c, 0x0e, 0x01, 0x03, 0x03, 0x03, 0x83, 0x80, 0x01, 0xc0, 0x30, 0x00, 0x30, 0x3f, 
  0xf0, 0x3c, 0x04, 0x0f, 0x01, 0x03, 0x03, 0x03, 0x83, 0xc0, 0x01, 0xe0, 0x38, 0x00, 0x30, 0x3f, 
  0xf0, 0x3e, 0x04, 0x0f, 0x81, 0x03, 0x03, 0x03, 0x83, 0xe0, 0x07, 0xf0, 0x3c, 0x00, 0xf0, 0x3f, 
  0xff, 0xff, 0xff, 0xff, 0xff, 0xff, 0xff, 0xff, 0xff, 0xff, 0xff, 0xff, 0xff, 0xff, 0xff, 0xff, 
  0xff, 0xff, 0xff, 0xff, 0xff, 0xff, 0xff, 0xff, 0xff, 0xff, 0xff, 0xff, 0xff, 0xff, 0xff, 0xff, 
  0xff, 0xff, 0xff, 0xff, 0xff, 0xff, 0xff, 0xff, 0xff, 0xff, 0xff, 0xff, 0xff, 0xff, 0xff, 0xff
};
```

*

This is for the splash screen when the device boots, right? ( see YT link )

Can someone explain what it means and how it's made? I want to create my custom splash screen but I don't understand this code. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I believe that is just a bitmap. The values indicate where to draw a pixel. The `0x00` values are just the blank space (probably black screen), and any where where there is a value greater than zero there will be pixels drawn (a `1` will be a pixel). All the painted pixels come together to create an image.

I think if you search, you should be able to find some kind of editor that will let you draw what you want and it will generate the bitmap for you.